# Switching from Ubuntu 20.04 to Kali without losing data

Tags: ubuntu, kali-linux

At the moment, I am using ubuntu 20.04 with a lot of packages and customization (i.e. bashrc and etc) which I need them for my work. I am thinking about using Kali, however, I do not have enough storage for a new partition, and also I cannot lose any data.

I was wondering if there is any way to switch to Kali except for backing up data to an external hard drive, formatting my drive, installing Kali and restoring data?

If there is no other way, what application do you recommend that's capable of backing up all data and restoring them without losing any information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason why you want to switch to Kali? I have the impression you want to do it because it has a fame of a "cool" and a "hacker" distro.

However, [Kali is not an all-purpose desktop distro](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/). It's a live distro aimed at pentesting with a very specific use case.

Very likely, the packages that you use in Ubuntu and you need for your work won't be available in Kali.

In short: **don't do it**.

Edit: You can install all Kali tools on Ubuntu via [Katoolin](https://ubunlog.com/en/katoolin-herramientas-kali-ubuntu) (I haven't tried it, this is the first result of a Google search). The opposite - trying to install your Ubuntu packages on Kali - will bring you to a world of pain several magnitudes greater.

Comment: You are mostly right. I need to do more research about moving to Kali. I like Kali since it has "cool" packages and tools, which I guess there should be a way to install them on ubuntu as well, but sometimes it is just a pain. However, there is another reason as well, I am curious about the experience of working with Kali. This is why I am looking for a safe way to switch, so if I didn't like Kali, I switch back to Ubuntu safely.

Comment: Also, thanks for the info. Appreciate it.

Comment: You can install all Kali tools on Ubuntu via Katoolin (I haven't tried it, this is the first result of a Google search): https://ubunlog.com/en/katoolin-herramientas-kali-ubuntu/ .  The opposite - trying to install your Ubuntu packages on Kali - will bring you to a world of pain several magnitudes greater.

Comment: Understood, Katoolin should work perfectly for me. Regarding experiencing working with Kali, I guess I can install it on a usb drive. Thanks a lot.